# How can I sort a FirebaseListObservable list in Angularfire2 Angular2?

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I want to get all users from a Firebase realtime database and sort them by a score property. I've got this to work using the variable
`users: FirebaseListObservable<any[]>;`
but I get the errors:

```
Type 'Observable<any[]>' is not assignable to type 'FirebaseListObservable<any[]>'.
Property '_ref' is missing in type 'Observable<any[]>'.
```

If I change the variable to
`users: Observable<any[]>;`
then the errors go away, but then I can't use the Angularfire methods like `.push()` and `.update()`.

My fetching and sorting code (which works) looks like:

```
this.users = this.af.database.list('/users')
  .map(items => items.sort((a, b) => b.score - a.score));
```

I would appreciate any advice on how this should be done to avoid the errors, or any preferred way, thank you!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `FirebaseListObservable` implements [`lift`](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/2.0.0-beta.4/src/database/firebase_list_observable.ts#L17-L23), so RxJS operators - like `map` - will return a `FirebaseListObservable` instance.

It's just that - when using TypeScript - the RxJS operators are statically typed to return `Observable`, so you have to cast to `FirebaseListObservable`. (Using RxJS does not have to involve TypeScript and if you look at [the guidance for adding operators](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJS/blob/master/doc/operator-creation.md#adding-the-operator-to-observable) you will see that types are not mentioned.)

You can verify that a `FirebaseListObservable` instance is returned by looking for the `push` and `update` functions you mentioned in your question:

```
this.users = this.af.database
  .list('/users')
  .map(items => items.sort((a, b) => b.score - a.score)) as FirebaseListObservable<any[]>;
console.log(this.users.push.toString());
console.log(this.users.update.toString());
```

Note, however, that this will not work for `FirebaseListObservable` instances that are created as queries. There is an [as-yet-unanswered question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37933985/6680611) regarding such instances.

Comment: @LindsayWard This is done on the client side.  For large set of data, you might want to sort on the server side.  Angularfire2 support a 2nd parameter in `list()` for sort by.

Comment: Thanks @Sam. Good to know. I'll try that as well and see if I notice any difference.

Comment: I get the following error:  `[ts] Property 'map' does not exist on type 'FirebaseListObservable<any[]>'.` Any ideas please?  I am using:     `"angularfire2": "^2.0.0-beta.7-pre",` and 
    `"firebase": "^3.6.4",`  More details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41550132/property-filter-does-not-exist-on-type-firebaselistobservable

Comment: @sam i added the sortBy in the query parameter. how can i specify the sorting - desc or asc?

Comment: @Sam, can i use any sort function in the 2nd parameter in list()? Can you please see this quesion https://stackoverflow.com/q/50112214/4299527 ?

Answer (score 2):

You need this example. To watch other opts see `Query` interface.

```js
this.items = angularFire.database.list('/users', {
  query: {
    orderByChild: 'childPropertyName'
  }
});
```

```js
export interface Query {
    [key: string]: any;
    orderByKey?: boolean | Observable<boolean>;
    orderByPriority?: boolean | Observable<boolean>;
    orderByChild?: string | Observable<string>;
    orderByValue?: boolean | Observable<boolean>;
    equalTo?: any | Observable<any>;
    startAt?: any | Observable<any>;
    endAt?: any | Observable<any>;
    limitToFirst?: number | Observable<number>;
    limitToLast?: number | Observable<number>;
}
```

Comment: Error: `Argument of type '{ query: { orderByChild: string; }; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'QueryFn'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'query' does not exist in type 'QueryFn'`