# Property 'filter' does not exist on type 'FirebaseListObservable'

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ionic2, angularfire

I am using Ionic 2 and Firebase to build a chat app.

I add the following which is supposed to be used to add a filter:

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/filter';
        ...
public af: AngularFire
        ...
    this.firelist = this.af.database.list('/chat/', {
      query: {
        orderByChild: 'negativtimestamp'
      }
    }).filter(item => item.memberIds === 'xxx');
```

However, I get the following:

> [ts] Property 'filter' does not exist on type
>   'FirebaseListObservable'.

ps. `this.af.database.list(...)` returns a `FirebaseListObservable<any[]>`. `filter` can be done on `Observable` but not on `FirebaseListObservable`.

**Question**

So how do I implement the `filter` on `FirebaseListObservable` because `class FirebaseListObservable<T> extends Observable<T>`?

**Also**

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'
            ...
    this.af.database.list('').map(item => {});
```

has the following error:

> [ts] Property 'map' does not exist on type 'FirebaseListObservable'.

**More Info:**

My `package.json` has:

```
 "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
```

[image]

Any help appreciated.

**UPDATE**

If you look at [the following youtube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8E-dueHCd2o), they do exactly what I want to achieve, but without the errors.  Does anyone know why I get errors? I am using `"angularfire2": "^2.0.0-beta.7-pre",`.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This issue was fixed in the following version:

`"angularfire2": "^2.0.0-beta.7.1-pre",`

Solution:

`npm install firebase angularfire2@^2.0.0-beta.7.1-pre --save`