# How to orderBy the closest distance from current location in AngularFire2?

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database, ionic3, angularfire2

I am using [AngularFire2](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2) library to query in firebase. In my firebase, i have **data** collection and in them, i have many rows with `latitude` and `longitude` like below:

```
- data
    - 1404033346513076_1998422263740845
        - location
           - latitude: 23.7907795
           - longitude: 90.403898
    - 1404033346513076_1998422263740888
        - location
           - latitude: 23.9907795
           - longitude: 91.403898
```

I have the `latitude` and `longitude` of my current location and i have a helper function which can determine the distance in meters between the current location and a location from the firebase data. Suppose, the function is like below:

```
calculateDistance(currentLoc, destLoc) {
  return routeDistance(currentLoc, destLoc); // It return in meters
}
```

Now, I need a query which will return 10 rows from the firebase which are at the sortest distance from the current location.

I know, i can query like below in firebase:

```
  constructor(private firebaseDBProvider: AngularFireDatabase) {
  }

  getDatas(): any {
    return this.firebaseDBProvider.list('data', ref => ref.orderByChild("location").startAt(0).endAt(3));
  }
```

But, it will not provide me the exact data i want.

Another thing, i have noticed is that, when i run below query, it return first 10 rows.

```
return this.firebaseDBProvider.list('data', ref => ref.limitToFirst(10));
```

But, if want to execute the below query, it returns me **0** rows.

```
this.firebaseDBProvider.list('data', ref => ref.startAt(0).endAt(10));
```

Why is that? **startAt** and **endAt** should work same as the **limitToFirst(10)**.

So, what should be the query so that i can return 10 rows which are the in the **sortest distance** from my current location?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two questions in your post. Let's try to answer each of them.

Q1: "I need a query which will return 10 rows from the firebase which are at the sortest distance from the current locationList item"

A1: As you may know, you will not be able to have the "Firebase database querying engine" triggering your `calculateDistance()` function while querying, i.e. Firebase can only sort based on the methods detailed here https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#sorting_and_filtering_data.

In other words, you will have to loop over the entire set of data from the `data` node in an environment that can execute your function: in your front-end or maybe in a Cloud Function (e.g. called by HTTPS, as a REST API)

---

Q2: "Why is that? startAt and endAt should work same as the limitToFirst(10)."

A2: No they are different.

As explained in the doc, "startAt() returns items greater than or equal to the specified **key or value**, **depending on the order-by method chosen**."

So first, you have to include a order-by-method at this line

```
this.firebaseDBProvider.list('data', ref => ref.startAt(0).endAt(10));
```

And secondly, depending on the order-by-method, this line is not going to necessarily return 10 records but all the records for which the order-by parameter is between 0 and 10.

Answer (score 0):

I think, using [GeoFire](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/06/geofire-20.html) can be a solution to get the data order by closest distance.