# @angular/fire: How to retrieve results with startAt() and endAt()

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm developing virtual scrolling for chat application designed with angular and firebase. The conversation messages are stored in firebase realtime database. 
[image]

(when we expand a child, the data looks like this)

[image]

I need to load last 50 conversations first, and then when the user scrolls up the chat, I need to load next 50 conversations and so on.

I tried to use `startAt(), endAt()` method to retrieve the data, but no results are returned from the firebase.

Comment: Can you share your code please? How do you exactly use startAt() and endAt()? You may have look at this SO question and answer, in particular answer #2 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50112214/how-to-orderby-the-closest-distance-from-current-location-in-angularfire2/50131985#50131985

Answer (score 1):

You need to use .limit(50) for first query and for consecutive queries use .limit(50) and .startAfter(). You don't have to use endAt or endAfter.

You also need to order the result according to some field and use same field for ordering for all queries.
So, for first Query:

```
ref.where(...).orderBy(...).limit(50);
```

then store the last document reference in the response.

For all consecutive queries:

```
ref.where(...).orderBy(...).startAfter(lastDocumentRef).limit(50);
```